# iPhone 6 - message saying accessory may not be supported

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an iPhone 6 which I recently updated to ios 11. Before the system update, I would occasionally get a notice saying "This accessory may not be supported" with a dismiss button. I have since updated to ios 11 but the notice still randomly appears. I know of nothing I do which triggers it or how it originated. Does anyone know how to stop this message from appearing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated my system to ios 11.2.1 and the message has stopped appearing. That seemed to be a fix.